# Route render prop not rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Does anyone know how to fix this:

```
<Route exact path="/post/:id" render={props => <Post {...props} />} />
```

When I use this code, no component is rendered when I clicked into the post page, but if I use:

```
<Route exact path="/post/:id" element={<Post />} />
```

I get this error msg:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'params')

on the `<Post/>` component this is the code:

```js
const validId = parseInt(props.match.params.id)
if (!validId) {
    return redirect("/404");
}
const fetchedPost = {}
let postExists = false
postlist.forEach((post, i) => {
    if (validId === post.id) {
        fetchedPost.title = post.title ? post.title : "No title given"
        fetchedPost.date = post.date ? post.date : "No date given"
        fetchedPost.author = post.author ? post.author : "No author given"
        fetchedPost.content = post.content ? post.content : "No content given"
        postExists = true
    }
})
```

Comment: After you fix/address accessing the route params issue using the `useParams` hook the next issue you'll hit is that `redirect` only works in Data Router route's loaders and action. You'll need to use the `useNavigate` hook and `navigate("/404")`.

Answer (score -1):

**Router code:**

```js
<Route exact path="/post/:id" element={<Post />} />
```

**Component code**:

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
.
.

const { id } = useParams(); // Gets the `id` param from url
```

> when i use this code, no component is rendered when i clicked into the post page

If you are using v6 of `react-router-dom`, `Route` doesnt have `render` prop and hence it just shows an empty page.